# How to install SSL Certificate in a sub-domain website?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, hosting

I have created a small online market in a sub domain like this:
shopName.mainDomainName.com
I need to install SSL certificate in this shop and possibly other shops in the future.

Can i install once in the main domain and reference that in the sub-domains?

Also, there are many options in SSL certificates that i got confused.
there are Dedicated,Business,and many other plans. from different companies such as comodo,symantech,... 
How to choose the right according to my small needs which are simplicity and price.

Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: First of all, are you on a shared hosting site? Most likely you are in a shared environment. In that case I don't think that there is an easy way to enable SSL unless there is an option in your control panel that allows you to do so.

Comment: I am using a dedicated server. Also, i have full control of all domains but not all of them needs ssl certificate. Although it would be nice if all of them can have it.

Comment: So, you own `mainDomainName.com` and all of its subdomains? Will answer after this.

Comment: I am not 100% sure. We have a dedicated server with that domain name from seedHost and we can create any number of subdomains.
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, you can avail a `Wildcard SSL` that works for these domain formats

**Wildcard SSL**

> Secures all subdomains but not the base domain itself
>
> Example:
>
> `*.mainDomainName.com`

Where the * represents any subdomain but not `mainDomainName.com`
itself.

**Subject Alternative Name**

> Secures all of the specified IP and DNS on the Subject Alternative Name of the Certificate.
>
> Example:
>
> `mainDomainName.com`
>
> `mainDomainName2.com`
>
> `login.mainDomainName.com`
>
> `*.mainDomainName.com`

As you can see, SAN SSL Certificates offer greater flexibility.

Choose among the given options above that meet your requirements

Comment: Tanks for the quick answer.Misaka-san or sama?. 
SAN SSL is the best for my situation. can recommend a provider with good prices? 
I will look for options but i want to hear your opinion.